# Direct html page access denied

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Can any one tell  me how can I prevent my html page to be access directly through URL I want it to be acccess by login members only actually my page contain an image(this page is developed on word press) which refers to html page and this page needs to be access by login member only. Can any one suggest any javascript code for it I have used  following script:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('flipbook_signup/wp-admin/profile/') == -1) 
{ 
   alert("Please Login!"); 
   top.location="http://google.com";
}
```

But its alerting a message in both conditions. Any other solution?

Comment: does your website have the DB?

Comment: yes wordpress db but i dnt want to go with session or cookies solution

Comment: i believe there is already some plugins for this like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/

Comment: JS is not secure enough to do that.

Comment: yes but that plugin will secure wordpress page only not html base page

Comment: @putvande any other solution u can suggest accept JS?

Comment: Maybe with an htaccess?

Comment: @putvande htaccess how? i don't know abt htaccess how can it help me??

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to do this by javascript, there you need to know or the user is logged in ...
You could add some PHP code (could be different for WP) in your HTML page:

```
<?php if ( $user_ID ) : // if logged in ?>

.... here your HTML code    
<?php else : // if not logged in go to login page 

    $url = 'register';
    header("Location:$url"); 

endif; // end if logged in
?>
```

And in .htaccess (allow php code in html):

```
<Files *.html>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```